# Private Files Readable

Tags: files

How can I fix this error on CiviCRM. Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preventing access to those files should be taken care of by `.htaccess` files.

You should have `.htaccess` files under `files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog`, `files/civicrm/upload`, `files/civicrm/custom` with content:

```
<Files "*">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

What webserver are you using?  Is this on a hosted environment or your own server?  The server needs to be configured to use `.htaccess` files

For Apache, see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride

For nginx, see other posts on this site - eg:

- [Files in the data directory (Upload | Custom)should not be downloadable. (Nginx)](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4042/files-in-the-data-directory-upload-customshould-not-be-downloadable-nginx)
- [Is CiviCRM compatible with Nginx?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27/is-civicrm-compatible-with-nginx)
- [Security Warning on Dashboard (pantheon / nginx)](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4460/security-warning-on-dashboard-pantheon-nginx)

Comment: I am using Nginx in AWS. How can I edit that .htaccess files. Thanks!

Comment: I find .htaccess from every directory, it shows that content. How can I edit and what config I need to input to prevent access? Thanks!

Comment: I've added links to nginx posts

Comment: Thanks Aidan! One last thing, all I need is to configure the nginx config to solved this problem, right? Also how about the CiviCRM debug log warning? Thanks

Comment: Yes, should just need some nginx config changes.  debug log is in the ConfigAndLog directory - ie same thing for each directory

Comment: what do you mean about debug log? inside ConfigAndLog dir? can you please easily explain to understand. Thanks so much.

Comment: The 3 warnings in your original post are all the same issue but referring to different directories.  With apache, those directories are protected via .htaccess files.  With nginx, you need to make a config change for the 3 directories in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the permissions on the hosting server for the directories in the warning. The directory permissions should be set to 0755, or it may show as 755. The files within the directories should show 0644, or 644.

Comment: Those file permissions still allow reads which is what the warning relates to.